# DOS batch command

Tags: batch-file, dos

I wonder if someone can help me in DOS batch command script.
The script will run two applications i.e. app1.exe, and app2.exe. First app1.exe will run and once app1.exe has finished running then the app2.exe will run.

(Please know app1.exe must finish running before app2.exe will start)

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "call"

```
call app1.exe
call app2.exe
```

Comment: Is it possible to run executable by CALL? I tried to do some research, but all I found is that it runs another batch file only.

Comment: yes, it seems to work on exe's as well. At least it does on Windows 7

Comment: Does `call app1.exe` `call app2.exe` really work differently for you from just `app1.exe` `app2.exe`? I could see no difference. Although I've known myself for some time that `CALL` can be used with executables, I haven't noticed any difference so far. Could you explain, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can force a sequence of programs by using

```
@echo off
start /WAIT /B app1.exe
start /WAIT /B app2.exe
```

/B means that the new app will be started without creating a new window.